# Apple Swift - Check to see if a character is present in a string

Tags: swift

Python:

```
myString = "hello python"
if "p" in myString:
    print "true"
```

Swift:

```
var myString = "is Swift really all it's cracked up to be?"
if myString.rangeOfString("c") != nil{
    println("true")
}
```

Is this really the "swiftest" (easiest) way to check to see if a character is present in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find `Character`, you can use builtin `contains` function:

```
if contains(myString, "c") {
    println("true")
}
```

If you want to find substring, `.rangeOfString("substring") != nil` is easiest.